# Web crawler can not retrieve results from google search

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am in the proccess of creating a simple webcrawler and I would like it to scrape the result webpage of a google search query such as "Donald Trump". I have written the follownig code:

```
# import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

paging_url = "https://www.google.gr/search? 
ei=fvtMW8KMI4vdwQLS67yICA&q=donald+trump&oq=donald+trump&gs_l=psy- ab.3..35i39k1j0i131k1j0i203k1j0j0i203k1j0l3j0i203k1l2.4578.6491.0.6763.12.9.0.0.0.0.447.879.4-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.2.878....0.aB3Y8R5B0U8"

req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.google.gr/search?ei=fvtMW8KMI4vdwQLS67yICA&q=donald+trump&oq=donald+trump&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i131k1j0i203k1j0j0i203k1j0l3j0i203k1l2.4578.6491.0.6763.12.9.0.0.0.0.447.879.4-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.2.878....0.aB3Y8R5B0U8", headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})

UClient = uReq(req)  # downloading the url
page_html = UClient.read()
UClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
results = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "srg"})
print(len(results))
```

A little bit of explaining about my thoughts and what Ι have noticed for the google page structure:

I am trying to get only the results of the search and not the reccomended videos or images that google also shows. When recommended videos or images are present nine results exist under two "div" tags with 'srg' class. Between Those "div" tags another "div" tag with the reccomended videos/images is inserted.

My problem is that the "div" tags that belong to the "srg" class can not be 'seen' by my code. I do not know why BeautifulSoup ignores them. The same thing happens with the "div" tags that belong to the "rc"
 class. Anyone with any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Try this selector `page_soup.select('div#ires div.g')[1:]`. I use it in my [github repo](https://github.com/tasos-py/searchengines/blob/master/core/engines.py#L11) to scrape google search results.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems using PhantomJS to make Webcrawlers to extract Google search data. On occasion I could navigate a few pages and then the system would be lost. In some situations I would see that in the resulting code it appeared that I was performing an illegal operation and that I should use the paid API "[Custom Search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)". The solution I found was to create the crawler from the Yahoo site. In case the result for me was satisfactory.

The Google API lets you do 100 free searches every day. Depending on the purpose of your application, this may be a quieter solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the only search results you can use the [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab CSS selectors either using `select()` (*can iterate over*) or `select_one()` (*grabs just **one** element*) `bs4` methods.

```py
for result in soup.select('CSS_SELECTOR'):
    ....
```

```py
soup.select_one('CSS_SELECTOR')
```

Code to scrape Title, Link, Displayed Link, and a Snippet and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Title-Link-Snippet-python?v=1):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'Donald Trump'}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# container with all needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf').a['href']
  displayed_link = result.select_one('.TbwUpd.NJjxre').text
  snippet = result.select_one('.VwiC3b.yXK7lf.MUxGbd.yDYNvb.lyLwlc').text
  
  print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n{snippet}\n')

# part of the output:
'''
Donald Trump | TheHill
https://thehill.com/people/donald-trump
https://thehill.com › people › donald-trump
12 hours ago — Donald Trump. Donald Trump. Getty Images. 0 Tweet Share More. Occupation: President of the United States, 2017 - 2021. Political Affiliation: Republican.
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Essentially, the difference is that you don't have to think about how to scrape stuff, bypass blockings, it's already done for the end-user. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Donald Trump",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  link = result['link']
  displayed_link = result['displayed_link']
  snippet = result['snippet']
  print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n{snippet}\n')

# part of the output:
'''
Donald Trump - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump
https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Donald_Trump
Donald John Trump (born June 14, 1946) is an American media personality and businessman who served as the 45th president of the United States from 2017 ...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.